# How to set style to a progressBar programmatically on Android

Tags: android, android-styles

I have ProgressBar style in style.xml.
When I create layout, put there ProgressBar and set style like:

```
style="@style/ProgressBarStyle"
```

set layout to dialog and all is fine.

Other way create view for dialog programmatically.
So for ProgressBar I have next code:

```
new ProgressBar(context, null, R.style.ProgressBarStyle);
```

But in this way there is nothing instead ProgressBar.

P.S. I don't forget add ProgressBar to view which I set as dialog view.

Comment: So your problem is that your custom style isn't applied on your progress bar?

Comment: isn't applied programmatically

Answer (score 23):

You can set your style from the constructor, for instance:

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```

Where the third attribute is the style.

In your case, I think the error is to choose a wrong one. Just this.

Comment: As I already wrote, I know about third attribute. If I choosed wrong one, why in xml this wrong one worked correctly?

Comment: Is it working for you? I'm not totally sure, but I would say that they are references for different things and that R.style.ProgressBarStyle is override by your own style (in styles folder) or even the default Android style you've set to the activity

Comment: ok, maybe I expressed not clearly. I have my own style called ProgressBarStyle. in R.style and @style i can find it. In xml all right (style applied to progress bar). But programmatycally something wrong, any progress bar isn't shown

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You have to pass the style through the 4th parameter `defStyleRes` not the 3rd parameter `defStyleAttr`.

```java
ProgressBar customProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, 0, R.style.Widget_App_CustomProgressBar);
```

Furthermore, the custom style you create should extend the `AppCompat` progress bar style as shown below.

```xml
<style name="Widget.App.CustomProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar</item>
</style>
```