# How to set Custom Theme for layout generated in code? (viewgroup)

Tags: android

> For my main activity following code sets theme to my custom one:
>
> ```
>     setTheme(R.style.Custom);
> ```
>
> but what about layout that I am getting from this:
>
> ```
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     ViewGroup layout = getLayout(getIntent().getStringExtra("key1"));
>     if (layout == null) return;
>     layout.addView(new ProgressBar(this));
>     layout.addView(new RadioButton(this));
>     layout.addView(new RatingBar(this));
>     layout.addView(new CheckBox(this));
>     layout.addView(new Switch(this));
>     layout.addView(new SeekBar(this));
>     layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3333ff"));
>     setContentView(layout);    }
> ```
>
> I want to change theme of ViewGroup layout, I tried
>
> ```
>     layout.setTheme(R.style.Custom); but it didn't work, what's the correct function to do this
> ```
>
> This is my theme code: (is it possible to change colors of stars, bar
>   etc in here?)

```
    <style name="Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#99ff99</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#009933</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#f542e3</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no attribute "theme" or something like that for ViewGroup.
Layout are used just to position your Widgets and nothing more than that

So you should either call `setTheme()` before everything else in `onCreate()` like that:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Custom);
}
```

or you can set custom styles to *every* widget (ProgressBar, RadioButton and etc.) via passing an attribute to every constructor [How to set style to a progressBar programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303558/how-to-set-style-to-a-progressbar-programmatically-on-android)